# How can I change the URL for my RSS feed on Wordpress from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https, rss

I am trying to use a bulk email service to send out emails whenever a new post is posted to my blog but any service I've tried hasn't been able to access the posts as they're going to an HTTPS address.

How would I send the posts to the HTTP feed instead of the HTTPS feed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You could use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/, its for sending bulk emails thrugh the a different server.

It will work however your site is set up http/https.

Comment: WPMandrill is a part of Mail Chimp right? I had been using MC before and was able to work around the issue but they felt that the blog's content was out of their TOS. I switched to Aweber because their TOS is more lenient but they don't offer the same workaround.

Slight long winded way of saying: I don't think I can use it.